# Calculating Android TextView's text capacity

Tags: android, android-widget

I have TextView with height and width as fill parent. Is it possible to find out how many characters can this layout hold?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how many characters can be entered into the textview and still be fully visible without scrolling? For proportional fonts, that will depend on the specific characters typed, including where the line break opportunities are. I don't think there's a simple way to compute that.